# Hysteresis in liquid–solid-phase transitions such as Agar

Tags: classical-mechanics, temperature

I'm wondering how it is possible for a substance to have a significantly different melting point than its freezing point. What physical interaction "locks" a substance such as Agar into the phase that it is currently in?

I presume that there must be some kind of force that needs to be overcome in at least one of the directions (for example, chains of molecules get tangled and to melt them requires a hirer temperature than it does to freeze them).

Comment: Possibly helpful (I haven't read thru it) http://books.google.com/books?id=DD5XAvr4bHMC&pg=PA348&lpg=PA348#v=onepage&q&f=false